# GridsearchCV to implement K fold on decision tree not working

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

So I have my training set that I got using sklearn train_test_split and I want to now use GridSearcCV to create 10 splits and find auc score for each d value from 2 to 10. Then I want to find the d value that gives the best auc score

This is my attempt but for the predict function, I have more features than required somehow

```
min_samples_list = list(range(2, 10))
tree_para = [{'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_list}]
cv = KFold(n_splits=10)

decisionTreeClassifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_leaf=k,random_state=0)
clf = GridSearchCV(decisionTreeClassifier, tree_para, cv=10)


fold_accuracy = []
for train_index, valid_index in cv.split(X_train):
    train_x,test_x = X_train[train_index],X_train[valid_index]
    train_y,test_y= y_train[train_index], y_train[valid_index]

    model = clf.fit(train_x,train_y)
    predicted_probs = model.predict([train_y])
    fold_accuracy.append(sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(predicted_probs, test_y)) 
    best_parameters = clf.best_params_
    print(best_parameters)

print("Accuracy per fold: ", fold_accuracy, "\n")
print("Average accuracy: ", sum(fold_accuracy)/len(fold_accuracy))
```

Answer (score 1):

In scikit-learn, the `predict()` method for all models uses input values X not the target value y (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.predict). That is why you have a problem with the number of features in the prediction.